# Product doesn't show on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I'm using latest version of Woocommerce plugin and the latest Wordpress version.
I add product and it's category programmatically.

```
$post_array = array(
     'post_author' => 'admin',
     'post_content' => 'aaaa,
     'post_title' => 'bbbb',
     'post_excerpt' => 'klkmlkmlk',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_type' => 'product'
);

wp_set_object_terms($postId, $category_term->term_id, 'product_cat', true );
```

On product edit page categories appear correctly in the widget on the right. When I look at category list in admin panel I can see that count number next to category has changed. Everything looks fine, but when I enter category page on the shop (front - not admin panel) as normal user I can't see that product there. But after opening this post in admin panel and clicking "Update" (when nothing is being changed) product appears for user too. I guess that I should refresh that product somehow to have it all right.